# Animation before API 11

Tags: android, animation

I've just found out found `android.animation.ObjectAnimator` was only introduced in Android API 11.

Is there any other way of animating objects on older android phones?

Answer (score -7, accepted):

`ObjectAnimator` is indeed introduced in Android 3.0(API Level 11), it cannot be found on 2.3.6.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/ObjectAnimator.html

Comment: Why did I not see that? I've looked at that page before.

Comment: Actually, do you know of any other way to animate before api 11?

Comment: At the right-top corner of the page, you will find `Since: API Level 11`.

Comment: Sure you can use [Animation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Animation.html) to animate your views.

Answer (score 28):

You can use Jake Wharton's NineOldAndroids [1] which is a backport of the Honeycomb new Animation Framework for 2.x Android devices. It is very easy to use, as it mimics the same API you would use on 11+ devices.

[1] http://nineoldandroids.com/

Comment: On Android 2.x, Object Animator doesn't work. Jake Wharton said that it is a problem of the platform and can't be fixed.

Comment: @NguyenMinhBinh: can you provide a source? I can't find where Jack Wharton has said that.

Comment: @NguyenMinhBinh dude don't provide false facts. It works perfectly using the NineOldAndroids I've just tried it.

Comment: LayoutTransitions don't work because of the platform. ObjectAnimator does.