# View Animations alternatives for API<11

Tags: android, android-animation, android-view

This [google API tutorial](http://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html) shows how to animate Views. However it uses methods that are available from API level 11, such as [View.setAlpha](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setAlpha%28float%29)

Now, using a phone with android 2.1 (API 7) I can find many , many applications using the same kind of animations (the card flip animation is very popular)

Are there any Google libraries to do the animations shown in this tutorial that would work with ANY API prior to 11?
If not, any other alternatives?

*P.S I am aware of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10267291/animation-before-api-11) But appearantly that was specifically about objectanimator and got an unuseful anser accepted*

Comment: use nineoldandroids jar it is the alrenative to ObjectAnimator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easy animation such as transform, rotate, move (which it seems to be what you want) may be made with such classes as:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/AnimationUtils.html

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/AnimatorSet.html

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Animation.html

In brief you will have create animation resources (or classes) and run it on views. After ending animation possibly you will have hide this view by visibility method.

Check this for details - http://jmsliu.com/779/android-view-animation-example.html.

Answer (score 1):

[NineOldAndroids](http://nineoldandroids.com/) will be able to provide you with animation APIs that you see in 11+. For example...

```
ViewHelper.setAlpha(view, 0);
```